# What is the best way to schedule a periodic task in react native (Android)?

Tags: android, react-native, android-workmanager

I have read past questions and answers regarding this in Stackoverflow. But couldn't find more up to date solution. There were some libraries available to do this task.

- [react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job)
- [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)
- [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)

The first two libraries are not updated recently. The third library uses Android's JobScheduler & AlarmManager API. Couldn't find a library which uses the Android's most recent more stable background task scheduler WorkManager API.

Is there any method to plug-in WorkManger to available in HeadlessJS in React Native? Or using Native Modules to implement that? I have previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547466/react-native-headlessjs-task-call-with-android-workmanager) in Stackoverflow with an implementation I got from [internet](https://medium.com/@shoaibmushtaq2/background-location-updates-in-react-native-using-work-manager-and-headless-js-91c0f0eab170). But it is not working correctly. Issue is highlighted in the relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547466/react-native-headlessjs-task-call-with-android-workmanager).